# Insert Query Works In SSMS but not SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a SQLCMD set to run in a batch script:

```
sqlcmd -S <SQL Server Instance> -U <USER NAME> -P <PASSWORD> -i "<Path to .sql file>"
```

*Note I need the quotes in the file path because it has spaces*

The .sql file is something like this.

```
INSERT  INTO Table2 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1 
,Col2
,Col3
FROM Table1
```

When I execute the SQL in Sql Server Management Studio it runs fine. I put a pause in the .bat file and it gives the message.

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Server , Line 1
> There is already an object named 'Table2' in the database.

Here is the query (obfuscated of course):

```
INSERT  INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6)
SELECT Col1
,Col2
,Col3
,Col4
,Col5
,cast(getdate() as date) as 'Col6'
FROM OrigTable 
WHERE exists(SELECT *
FROM ChkTable
WHERE DateCol > '20140101'
and OrigTable.Col1 = ChkTable.Col1)
and not exists(SELECT *
FROM Table1 inner join (SELECT max(Col6) as 'TopDate'
                          ,Col1
                          FROM Table1
                          GROUP BY Col1) a
on Table1.Col6 = a.TopDate
and Table1.Col1 = a.Col1
WHERE Table1.Col1 = OrigTableCol1
and (Table1.Col5 = OrigTable.Col3
or isnull(Table1.Col4,1) = isnull(OrigTable.Col4,1)))
```

Comment: "something like this" is not good enough. Show the full, exact code run in both circumstances. An `insert` statement cannot fire an error about trying to create a table. So you must be running something else in that case.

Comment: Either your sql is more like `select ... into Table2 from ...` or your sql files (in SSMS vs in CMD) are actually different ones.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, is it not? The code in your file is trying to create an object, but an object with that name already exists.

Comment: I thought by specifying the columns it would not try to create the table. @allmhuran

Comment: As the other comments have mentioned, `insert into ...` won't create a table, so there is something else in your script. I expect Avro is correct, the script is using `select into` instead of `insert into`. But without seeing the real code we can only guess.

Comment: That command cannot throw the error shown. Your command just insert data, but the error is about creating an existing table. Show the actual script.

Comment: In some part of the code executed by the `SQLCMD` it is trying to create the table `Table2` and it already exists in the database

Comment: Oops. Messed up the table name obfuscation a bit. Fixed now.

Comment: @underscore_d I was going to say it should be sufficient, but I did some quick tests building tables and testing and a "simple" insert into one table from another works both in SSMS and SQLCMD. However, the one I added with the edit works fine in SSMS, but not SQLCMD. I'm wondering if it gets parsed differently due to the exist statements.

Comment: Still nowhere in that code does anything do anything even remotely resembling trying to create `Table2`, so unless you have found a new bug in SQL Server itself, you must not be showing the actual/full code.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on `Table1`? Your original code said `insert into Table2`, but your new code says `Insert into Table1`. This opens up a new possibility: There is a trigger on `Table1` that is trying to create `Table2`.

Comment: @Michael, I think you left the table creation script in the same directory as the script you want to use, and with that he is trying to create the table again

Comment: @Michael. Accept as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the table creation script from the directory you are using.